# How to recognize Razor Code within a String of HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am parsing a string of HTML Code within my Razor view:

```
 <label>Now, Mr./Mrs.    
      @Html.ViewData.Model.Patient.LastName.First().ToString().ToUpper()
      @Html.ViewData.Model.Patient.LastName.Substring(1).ToLower(),
              I must verify some important information before we begin:</label>
```

using `@HTML.Raw();` as well as `@WriteLiteral();` which processes the HTML Label tag fine, however, I want it to process the Html Helper calls prior to generating the Label by inserting the values of my Model.

Is there a best practice to get this to function?  Is there some type of "parser" that will recognize my Razor Code prior to generating HTML?

Comment: isn't it better to pass this values over the viewBag for example?

Comment: This is not the best way to do something like this. Why don't you just put that literal string statically inside your view? Instead of dynamically inserting it into your view?